# Segmentation fault after resizing array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to implement an algorithm, which sorts words up to a length of 100 chars alphabetically. 
My idea was to take in each word using `fgets()`, then check if its length is under 100 chars and if so, put it into an array of strings after correspondingly resizing it.

But, now I'm getting a segfault in Line 37, which is supposed to use the `strcpy()` function to put the string into my string array.

I am pretty sure the resizing of the array is responsible for the error. This is because the segfault only occurs at the 2nd word (ie, 2nd iteration of the while-loop).

This is the code I have used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b){
    const char* aa = *(const char**)a;
    const char* bb = *(const char**)b;
    return strcmp(aa,bb);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //buffer array to check word length
    char barray[102];
    char* buffer = barray;

    //main array pointer
    char** list;
    list = (char**)calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    //if calloc fails
    if(list == NULL){
        perror("calloc() fails at main array");
        return -1;
    }

    //memory allocation for first string
    list[0] = (char*) calloc(102, sizeof(char));
    if(list[0] == NULL){
        perror("calloc() fails at first array element");
        return -1;
    }

    //string array index
    int counter = 0;

    //print flag
    int flag = 0;

    //create unsorted list
    while(fgets(buffer, 103, stdin) != NULL){
        //breakpoint 1
        if(buffer[0] == '\n'){
            break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 101;i++){
            //if word is of legit length and not the last one
            if(buffer[i] == '\n'){
                buffer[i] = '\0';
                strcpy(list[counter], buffer); //segfault at 2nd iteration
                counter++;
                list = realloc(list, (counter + 1)  * sizeof(char*));
                list[counter] = (char*)calloc(102,sizeof(char));
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag==1){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }   
        //if word is too long
        if(buffer[100] != '\0'){
            printf("Word too long!");
        }
        else{
            strcpy(list[counter], buffer);
            counter++;
        }

    }

    //sort list
    qsort(list, counter, sizeof(char*), cmpstr);

    //print list
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        printf("%s\n", list[i]);
    }

    //free memory
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        free(list[counter]);
    }
}
```

PS: Also, please feel free to criticize my code or if you see any other mistakes that I have made :)

Comment: how do you compile and run?

Comment: You should not fgets up to 103 bytes into a buffer that can only hold 102.

Comment: In addition, at the end of while you increase counter but do not reallocate, so, it seems, the next strcpy call fails.

Comment: Err, it appears the code as you have it will never read the second line because of the `flag/break` thingy.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/uacfFz)

Answer (score 1):

Well yeah, it looks like you set `list = (char**)calloc(1, sizeof(char*));` which means you only have space for one `char*` in `list`. So when you try to `strcpy` into `list[1]` you segfault.